# Is it ever correct to say "no people is better"?

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number

My friend asks me, "Would you rather have no people there, or should I invite someone to go with you?" I reply, "No people is better."

Is this grammatically correct? I interpret the sentence as really saying "[Having] no people is better." But phrases like "Two heads are better than one" seem to imply otherwise.

Comment: Well, There's no people like show people. It's fine. Just make sure your friend doesn't hear *No, people is better*.

Comment: It's fine. You're effectively using ***no people*** to reference ***one*** of two possible states, irrespective of how many people might be present in each of those states. Same principle as [***three is** better than two*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22three+is+better+than+two%22), where semantically the reference is to ***a*** (singular) number, not the "plural value" of the number.

Answer (score 1):

*No* can be a determiner in front of a noun to express the absence of any instances of whatever the noun talks about it.  It works with countable and non-countable nouns.

> I wanted people to be there.
>
> I wanted no people to be there.
>
> Water was on the floor.
>
> No water was on the floor.
>
> The project was completed today.
>
> No project was completed today.